# Applying a function to a list of indexes of a vector?

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop

I have a vector `X` of length `n`, and a list of indices `L` of variable length. Let `F` be a function from R^m to R. I want to apply the function `F` to each subvector `X[L[[i]]`. This is, I want to calculate `F( X[ L[[i]] ] )`

For example, suppose that `F` is the mean

```
set.seed(123)
X <- rnorm(100)
L <- list()
for(i in 1:10) L[[i]] <- sample(1:100,30,replace = FALSE)
```

By brute force I could calculate

```
out <- vector()
for(i in 1:10) out[i] <- mean(X[ L[[i]] ])
```

However, this for loop is rather slow for larger dimensions. I was wondering if there is a more direct way for calculating out? I have tried to use `lapply` but it does no seem to work for the combination of a vector + a list of indices + a function.

Comment: Try `lapply(L, function(i) mean(X[i]))`

Comment: @Sotos  That seems to do the trick. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @SnoopDogg keep in mind that direct way may not be the fastest

Comment: @slava-kohut Interesting comment. I will take a look at the running times.

Comment: @SnoopDogg use to `vector(n, mode = "list")` to create a vector to fill in. This will avoid expensive copying in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `lapply` to loop over your list and use each element to subset your vector `X`. Once you subset, calculate the mean, i.e.

```
lapply(L, function(i) mean(X[i]))
```

Comment: I don't think this will be faster than a for loop (but I might be wrong). Can you post some timings?

Comment: I don't doubt the quality of your answer. The OP's ultimate goal was to speed up their calculation, and they hoped they would achieve this with `lapply` (which I doubt). The function form does not matter.

Comment: In my specific application, one evaluation went from 95s to 71s (after using `lapply` instead of `for`). I am not sure if this is a generalizable improvement, or something related to way I implemented the function, which is a several lines long.